# R matching dataframe before and after regression with missing values and subset regression

Tags: r, regression

I have included a toy example to recreate my error:

```
data(cars)
cars$dist[cars$dist<5]<-NA
cars$fast<- (cars$speed>10)*1

fit<-lm(speed~dist,cars)


cl   <- function(dat,fm, cluster){
  require(sandwich, quietly = TRUE)
  require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
  M <- length(unique(cluster))
  N <- length(cluster)
  K <- fm$rank
  dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
  uj  <- apply(estfun(fm),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum));
  vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
  result<-coeftest(fm, vcovCL)
  return(result)}

cl(cars,fit,cars$fast)

Error in tapply(x, cluster, sum) : arguments must have same length
```

The issue is that the original dataframe is bigger than the dataframe used in the regresssion due to the removed NA's and subset regression. I need to compute the robust standard errors, so I have to compute the SEs with the function cl, but how do I identify the NAs removed and appropriately subset so I can identify the correct cluster to go with the dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I inquire why you have "dat" in the argument list since the `cl` function does not reference it?

Comment: You are correct, I should remove that. Since cluster is a vector that supposedly matches the dataframe used in the regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `complete.cases` to indentify the NAs in your data but in this case it will be better to use the information in your `lm` object on the way it handled NA's (Thanks to @Dwin for pointing better way to access this information and more generally how to simplify this answer).

```
data(cars)
cars$dist
cars$dist[cars$dist < 5] <- NA
cars$fast<- (cars$speed > 10) * 1
which(!complete.cases(cars))
## [1] 1 3

fit <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
fit$na.action
## 1 3 
## 1 3 
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "omit"
```

Therefore, your final function should like this

```
cl   <- function(fm, cluster){
    require(sandwich, quietly = TRUE)
    require(lmtest, quietly = TRUE)
    M <- length(unique(cluster))
    N <- length(cluster)
    K <- fm$rank
    dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
    uj  <- apply(estfun(fm),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster[-fm$na.action], sum));
    vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
    result<-coeftest(fm, vcovCL)
    result}

cl(fit,cars$fast)
## t test of coefficients:

##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)   8.8424     2.9371    3.01  0.00422
## dist          0.1561     0.0426    3.67  0.00063
```

Comment: Rather than the "double negative" you could just use `cluster[complete.cases(dat)]`, but my preference would be to use the `cluster[-fit$na.action]` vector.

Comment: First, thanks for the help! I realized I made a mistake in my question. I guess missingness (NA) is not the only source of where the dataframe in the regression is smaller. Some of my regression are subset regression. So my proposed solution is to subset the original dataframe with the same subset parameters and then perform the regression? Is there a more elegant way to do this?